# Visual studio showing same output when run a different program

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide

Im newbie, in visual studio 2012 i have 2 tabs of different program when i try to run second program it gives output of first program, for example one program has outputs "hello world" and second program has output "hello cat", when i run program of hello cat it gives hello world, why is this happens? how can i solve this problem?

Comment: these are two projects of console applications

Answer (score 4):

Right click on the project that outputs "hello cat" and click "Set as StartUp Project".

In Visual Studio a solution may hold none or many runable applications. The project with the bolded text is the project that will run when you click "Start".

Answer (score 1):

**Problem :**  you are running the same project/program always.

**Solution 1:**

Select the project you want to run.
Right click on it.
Select `Debug` Option
Select `Start new instance`.

**Solution 2:**

Select the project you want to run.
Right Click on it.
Select `Set as startup project`.
Now run the project.

EDIT: when you right click on the Project( not on Solution) you will get following ContextMenu from there you can find above mentioned options to proceed further.

[image: Project ContextMenu]

[image]

Comment: set as startup project is in project button(m i right saying it button or something else i forget i think!), when i right click on selected project i didn't show up set as startup project, neither start new instant on right click

Comment: did you select the project and right click on it? it will show you `Set as startup project` . which version of Visual Studio you are using?

Comment: yes i did the same right click in the targeted project window and i am using VS 2012

Comment: From where you got this contextmenu, i don't know where is the project to click right on, in the beginning, from file i selected new project and selected c# console application, and thats it, i just have this knowledge about project and solution is the window  where the code is written i think

Comment: please add the snap shot for project and where to right click please!

Comment: Thank you i understood, but this project is not changing even if i switch to other solution(tabs), and when i set as startup project it run the same solution as earlier, i think in a project there are multiple solutions(tabs) m i right?

Answer (score 1):

Note that you don't have 2 different programs open in the tabs but instead 2 different files each one belonging to a different project.  When you hit run / F5 Visual Studio doesn't decide what to run based on the selected file.  Instead it will attempt to run the project which is currently labeled as the start up project. Hence simply changing the active tab won't have any effect on what is run.

If you want to change the project which is being run then right click on the target project and select "Set as Startup Project".  The project which is currently the startup project will be displayed in bolt text

Comment: @user2917063 open up solution explorer and it will list the projects in the current solution